# How to exclude some views when animating with Shared Element

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-element-transition

FAB and AdMob's banner ad view is not fading immediately during transition of views that has shared element.

I have the below setup and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sxTM37cGC1auMJXIpK7nzrr_R0EWudQt/view?usp=share_link) is how it currently looks like.

RecyclerView ItemView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/space_16"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/space_4">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:transitionName="featured_image"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark_Primary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_colored" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/space_12"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize16"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/postTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/space_8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_12"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/date/mmddyy" />

    <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/labelHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/space_16"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_4"
        android:text="@string/related_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize12"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Second Activity

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".presentation.BlogViewActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:maxLines="3">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/featuredImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:transitionName="featured_image"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite_PrimaryDark"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:title="@string/vwap" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
                android:id="@+id/description_html_txt_v"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/space_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/space_48"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_12"
                android:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize14" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/space_16"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/space_12"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_8"
                    android:text="@string/related_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark_Accent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize24" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/feedRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/space_12" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/visitWeb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_12"
        android:contentDescription="@string/news"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_open_tab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside a fragment class

```
val optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    requireActivity(),
                    featuredImage,
                    featuredImage.transitionName
                )

startActivity(Intent(this@with, BlogViewActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(BlogViewActivity.INTENT_NEWS, domain)
                }, optionsCompat.toBundle())
```

There is also noticeable glitch with `BottomNavigationView`.
Is there a way to immediately hide some views when the activity of target view is exiting?